# Regex - everything except slash

Tags: php, regex

I wrote small routing system, but I have problem with it. My regex is reading slash as a normal string and I've got confused how to make it working. For example:

I defined route `home/[a-zA-Z0-9_]` that will show profile, but i defined also `home/user/\d`. When I write down second case, `home/user/45`, it will write down first case. It will take `user/45` as one string. How I can exclude that `/` using regex.

Comment: what you have now should exclude the `/`. There must be more going on that there appears? (Or you need to add the end of string anchor (`$`))

Comment: Post some code here to get better help.

Comment: Please post some code, PHP as well as your RewriteRules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should match the following pattern:

```
/home\/user\/(\\d+)/
```

And replace it with the following:

```
home/user$1
```

In the first regex, I used a delimiter: a slash. If a delimiter isn't required, remove the first and the last slash.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this?

```
[^\/]+
```

Or better

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[^\/]+
```

If you go to [regexr.com](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) and put your string ( `home/user/45` ) it will select only `home,user,45` (excepting the slash `/`)

Answer (score 0):

try home/(?!user/)[a-zA-Z0-9_] 
for first case

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

```
<?php

$path = '/home/user/45';
preg_match_all('/home\/(\w+)/', $path, $matches);
/* Would set $matches to Array:
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => home/user
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => user
    )
)
*/

preg_match_all('/home\/(\w+)/(\d+)/', $path, $matches);
/* Would set $matches to Array:
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => home/user/45
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => user
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 45
    )
)

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trusting the regex on this you really should limit the pattern. And also another trick to make patterns more readable is to use another pattern character:

```
|^/home/(\w+)/?$|
|^/home/user/(\d+)/?$|
```